# i can't install albumentations[imgaug]

Tags: albumentations

There are two options to fix this error:

1. [Recommended]. Switch to the Albumentations' implementation of the augmentation with the same API: Affine - https://albumentations.ai/docs/api_reference/augmentations/geometric/transforms/#albumentations.augmentations.geometric.transforms.Affine
2. Install a version of Albumentations that contains imgaug by running 'pip install -U albumentations[imgaug]'.

That's my mistake. I've tried the second method, but it didn't work. I don't quite understand the first one